# Failure to read field data using foriegn key from different table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Please I am trying to access the field name in my categories table using the foreign key category in my products table but I keep getting Attempt to read property "name" on int error

these are my relationships in Product.php and Categories.php respectively

```
//product
    namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Categories;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'tags' => 'array',
        'colors' => 'array',
        'other_images' => 'array'
    ];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, "category");
    }



 //categories
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Models\Product;
    
    class Categories extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        protected $guarded = ['id'];
    
        public function products(){
            return $this->hasMany(Product::class, "category");
    }
    
    }
```

and this is my blade template

```
@if ($product->count())
            @foreach ($product as $index => $product)
            <button type = "button" class = "btn m-2 text-dark" data-filter = ".{{$product->category}}">{{$product->category->name}}</button>
            @endforeach
        @endif
```

the category field is a foreign key with the reference id in categories table

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have in your products table column with name `category_id`, if that's the case then you should remove "category" from

```
 public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, "category");
}
```

to be

```
 public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class);
}
```

in your Product model

Please refer to this part in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship)

Also, change the relationship in

```
public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, "category");
}
```

to be

```
public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Comment: instead of category_id, the field that stores the category id  in products table is called category

Comment: Please after removing the "category", I still get the error

Comment: Change 
foreach ($product as $index => $product)
            <button type = "button" class = "btn m-2 text-dark" data-filter = ".{{$product->category}}">{{$product->category->name}}</button>

to

foreach ($product as $index => $p)
            <button type = "button" class = "btn m-2 text-dark" data-filter = ".{{$p->category}}">{{$p->category->name}}</button>